Swagger Documentation For A Generic Base Api Controller
I've been developing an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using Swagger UI to automatically document resources extracted from my OpenAPI specification, however I've run into an issue when using generics.
In the API, I have a handful of resources that inherit from a base controller, which themselves are documented fine, however it seems that Swagger is unable to generate documentation for the base controller because of the use of generics.
Here's an example of my base controller, which is missing from the Swagger documentation:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PersonController<TEntity> : ControllerBase
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly ILogger<PersonController<TEntity>> _logger;
    private readonly IPersonService _personService;
    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public PersonController(ILogger<PersonController<TEntity>> logger,
        IPersonService personService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _personService = personService;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    [HttpGet("GetById/{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> GetById(int id)
    {
        TEntity person = await _personService.GetByIdAsync<TEntity>(id);

        return Ok(person);
    }
    #endregion
}


Is there anyway of documenting a controller in Swagger when using generics?

I'm afraid this is by design, Swagger might expect concrete controller types. I had a test with your code snippet and reproduced the issue. Then I define public class CustomerController : PersonController<Customer>  which will show me the API. https://i.sstatic.net/WL2cnRwX.png
